# Add pound sign to jquery range slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have a jQuery range slider on my site, when it hasn't yet been used the £ signs show. But the moment you change the value by using the slider the £ signs are removed. Any way to get them to stay?

Here is the code so far:

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here
    $("#submitFilter").hide();
    $(".filterCheck").change(function(){
        $("#submitFilter").click();
    });
    $(".filterCategoryCheck").change(function(){
        document.location = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
    });
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: <?php echo $rootPriceFrom; ?>,
        max: <?php echo $rootPriceTo; ?>,
        values: [<?php echo $priceFrom; ?>, <?php echo $priceTo; ?>],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#priceFrom").val(values[0]);
            $("#priceTo").val(values[1]);
            $("#spanPriceFrom").html(values[0]);
            $("#spanPriceTo").html(values[1]);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //alert('a');
            $("#priceGo").click();
        }
    });
    $("#priceFrom").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
    $("#priceTo").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
         <div id="rangedval">Price Range: <span id="rangeval">&#163;<?php echo $priceFrom; ?> - &#163;<?php echo $priceTo; ?></span></div>
        <div id="rangeslider"></div>
         <input type="text" id="priceFrom" name="priceFrom" style="display:none;"/>
        <input type="text" id="priceTo" name="priceTo" style="display:none;"/>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" id="priceGo" value="Search">
```

Live URL - http://bit.ly/Iol1jG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the pound sign to the spans in the slide event as it follows:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: <?php echo $rootPriceFrom; ?>,
    max: <?php echo $rootPriceTo; ?>,
    values: [<?php echo $priceFrom; ?>, <?php echo $priceTo; ?>],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#priceFrom").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#priceTo").val(ui.values[1]);
        $("#rangeval").html("£"+ui.values[0]+" - £"+ui.values[1]); //edited part
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        //alert('a');
        $("#priceGo").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Added but unfortunately still the exact same.

Comment: try to inspect what is the id/class of the element showing the values and change the edited part ids to suit your code, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: true,
        values: [ 17, 67 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
```

REFERENCE

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical

for your code it will be like **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yb3tD/)**

```
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#spanPriceFrom").html("£" + ui.values[0]);
            $("#spanPriceTo").html("£" + ui.values[1]);
        }
```